# Binary conversion app

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to ruby and programming in general.

I had an idea for a fun little project that I could use to gain a little experience. I wrote a simple program that takes a 4 bit binary sequence (ie. 1001, 1110, etc) and converts it into its decimal counterpart (ie 1111 = 15). I got the program working but even I can tell it's pretty ugly and limited code. I've been racking my brain trying to figure out a way to improve and I'm thinking if I do something similar to this app (converting to an array and reversing so i can work left to right instead of right to left) but instead of hard coding the if statements for each digit I could use a loop that just doubles the last digit and add that to the sum if it's a one in that spot.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# binary_conversion.rb


puts "
    ***************************************************
            BINARY CONVERSION TOOL
                VERSION: 0.1
            CREATED BY: Micky Scandal
    ***************************************************
"
sleep(1)
again = 0
while again != "n"
    @zero = 0
    @one = 0
    @two = 0
    @three = 0
    @bin_input = ""
    until @bin_input.length == 4                                    # && bin_input.class == Fixnum
        print "Please enter a 4 bit binary string (ex: 0110):> "
        @bin_input = gets.chomp
    end
    puts "You entered #{@bin_input}"

    @bin_array = @bin_input.to_s.split(//).map(&:to_i)
    @bin_array.reverse!
    p @bin_array
    puts "converting..."; sleep(0.5)

    if @bin_array[0] == 1
        @zero = 1
    end
    if @bin_array[1] == 1
        @one = 2
    end
    if @bin_array[2] == 1
        @two = 4
    end
    if @bin_array[3] == 1
        @three = 8
    end

    ans = @zero + @one + @two + @three
    puts "answer is #{ans}"
    puts ""
    puts "Run again? (Y/N)"
    again = gets.chomp
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO and glad you are learning Ruby.
You know there are easy ways in Ruby to do convertions between numbers ?
If not take a look at this blog http://rubyquicktips.com/post/18935873770/convert-between-number-bases-easily

Answering your question: you have a lot of boiler code which you could cut by taking the exponent of each digit like here under. While I still could do this shorter by injecting an object instead of declaring the dec = 0 I won't do so for readability.

I use the method each_char on the string to split into a character array and daisychain this result to another method with_index that adds... yes an index.
Then I use the formula below to add the exponent of that char multiplied by 2 (the base) converted to an integer taking into account the position in the string.
This is not the best algorithm by far to do this, just an example how to use these methods to shorten your code and make it more 'Rubylike'.
If you search for good exercises which you can test and compare your results with others solutions taka a look at https://www.codewars.com

Happy code learning !

```
bin_input = "1111"
puts bin_input.to_i(2)  #=> 15 this is the normal Ruby way

# This is our educational way
dec = 0
print dec
bin_input.to_s.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
  dec += (char.to_i*2)**(bin_input.length-(index+1))
  puts "+(#{char.to_i*2})**(#{bin_input.length-(index+1)})"
end
puts dec # 15
```

Which gives

```
15
0+(2)**(3)
+(2)**(2)
+(2)**(1)
+(2)**(0)
15
```

Answer (score 3):

If `str = "1101"`, the decimal equivalent is, by definition,

```
1*(2**3) + 1*(2**2) + 0*(2**1) + 1*(2**0) #=> 13
```

This can be written in Ruby, for any string of zeroes and ones, as follows:

```
str = "1101"
n = str.size - 1
  #=> 3
(0..n).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + str[i].to_i*(2**(n-i)) }
  #=> 13

str = "1001110101"
n = str.size - 1
  #=> 9 
(0..n).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + str[i].to_i*(2**(n-i)) }
  #=> 629
```

See the doc for [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`)<sup>1</sup>.

When you are unsure what is happening with your (or someone else's) code, insert some `puts` statements. Here that might be as follows.

```
str = "1101"
n = str.size - 1
  #=> 3
(0..n).reduce(0) do |t,i|
   puts "i=#{i}, t=#{t}"
   puts "  str[#{i}].to_i*(2**(#{n}-#{i}))=#{str[i].to_i*(2**(n-i))}"
   t + str[i].to_i*(2**(n-i))
end
i=0, t=0
  str[0].to_i*(2**(3-0))=8
i=1, t=8
  str[1].to_i*(2**(3-1))=4
i=2, t=12
  str[2].to_i*(2**(3-2))=0
i=3, t=12
  str[3].to_i*(2**(3-3))=1
  #=> 13
```

Here is a variant of the above calculation, which is a good example of *chaining methods* in Ruby:

```
str = "1101"
str.each_char.reverse_each.with_index.reduce(0) { |t,(c,i)| t + (c.to_i << i) }
  #=> 13
```

See [Array#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each) and [Fixnum#<<](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C).

The following is an optional extra that is not directly related to your question.  In the code directly above, the first value passed to the block will be

```
[0,["1",0]]
```

Where the first zero equals `reduce`'s *memo* (or accumulated value), represented by the block variable `t`, `"1"` is the first character of `str` and `0` is that character's index in `str`. By writing the block variables as `t,(c,i)`, we obtain, using *disambiguation* and *parallel (or multiple) assignment*, the following:

```
t,(c,i) = [0,["1",0]]
t #=> 0 
c #=> "1" 
i #=> 0
```

<sup>1 You can do this without using `reduce`, but using `reduce` here is the *Ruby way*. You can think of `[1,2,3].reduce(0) { |t,n| t + n} #=> 6`, for example, as a more compact form of `t = 0; [1,2,3].each { |n| t += n}; t #=> 6`.</sup>

Comment: `t + (c.to_i)*(2**i)` can be written as `t + (c.to_i << i)`. And if you had a `bits` array of `1`s and `0`s, you could even write `bits.reverse_each.with_index.map(&:<<).inject(:+)`

Comment: Good point, @Stefan. I changed my "variant" to use that.

Comment: @Stefan, that's an even better example of chaining: `str.each_char.map(&:to_i).reverse_each.with_index.map(&:<<).inject(:+)`. (Whew!).

Answer (score 3):

[Ruby has built in methods to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339695/how-to-convert-a-string-or-integer-to-binary-in-ruby#2340415), but doing it yourself it's a good exercise in handling input and doing things in loops.

In general when programming, if you're ever hard coding variables like `@zero`, `@one`, `@two` there is something wrong. I think you've realized this. In general it means you need to use lists and loops.

First, let's tidy up getting input and separate that from the conversion.

```
loop do
  print "Enter a binary number: "
  binary = gets.strip
  break if binary == ''

  if binary.match('[^01]')
    puts "#{binary} does not look like a binary number";
    next;
  end

  puts base2dec(2, binary)
end
```

`loop` does an infinite loop. When you're not looping on a simple variable, when the variable needs extra processing, it's often simpler to break out of an infinite loop rather than try to do all the processing in the loop condition. This is *very* common for looping over user input which can be messy.

`binary = gets.strip` takes the place of `chomp`. It both removes the newline and any extra whitespace that might have slipped in. I've also done a check that it looks like a binary string to prevent trying to work on garbage. Garbage In, Error Out.

Instead of using `n` to stop input, I've simply used a lack of input. This is another nice side effect of `binary = gets.strip`. YMMV.

Now we have a nice, clean binary string that can be passed along to our conversion function, `base2dec`. This lets us focus on and test one thing at a time.

```
def base2dec(base, binary)
  sum = 0
  place = 1

  # Read the string from right to left
  # Least to most significant digit
  max_idx = binary.length - 1
  max_idx.downto(0) { |i|
    # Get the digit character, convert it to an integer
    digit = binary[i].to_i(base)

    # Sum it according to the current place (like "4s place")
    sum += digit * place

    # Prepare for the next place (like 4 -> 8)
    place *= base
  }

  return sum
end
```

Even though we're asking for binary, I decided to go with a base-agnostic algorithm just to further demonstrate making things generic. I avoided using too many Rubyisms so the algorithm is clear, but [`downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-downto) was too tempting to resist.

This counts through the string starting at the end (right to left). This counts the least significant digits first. I could have started at the front (most significant digit), it just felt more natural. As far as the algorithm is concerned there's not a big difference.

The `place` is stored and multiplied by the base (1's place, 2's place, 4's place, 8's place...). This, and the loop, avoids having `@zero`, `@one`, `@two`...

Using [String#to_i(base)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) is not really cheating, it just avoids having to write your own converter from hex should you want to use this for something like base 16.

`base2dec` will handle bases 2 to 36, and that limit is only because of `String#to_i`. And, because of the algorithm and Ruby's awesome ability to transparently handle arbitrarily big numbers, it will handle any length you want.

```
$ ruby ~/tmp/test.rb
Enter a binary number: 111111111111111111111111111111111111
68719476735
Enter a binary number: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
21267647932558653966460912964485513215
```